# Conditions for positive definite Symmetric Toeplitz matrix with powers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $A_n$ be the following matrix for $p\leq 1$:
\begin{equation}
A_n = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2^{-p} & 3^{-p} & \dots & n^{-p} \\
2^{-p} & 1 & 2^{-p} & \dots & (n-1)^{-p} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
n^{-p} & (n-1)^{-p} & (n-2)^{-p} & \dots & 1.
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

How do I show whether this matrix is positive definite or not? Numerically, it seems to be positive definite. I've tried to show this by showing the Cholesky decomposition exists, but the expressions I get are confusing.

Comment: @WillJagy So I've got $A_{ij} = \int_0^1 x^{(i - j + 1)^p-1} dx$, but I'm not sure how to break this up even further given $p>0$ is arbitrary......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_n(x)$ be the $n\times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $x^{|i-j|}$. It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86316) that $B_n(x)$ is positive definite for $|x|<1$. Now the fact that $A_n$ **is positive definite** follows easily from $$A_n=\frac1{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^1(-\log x)^{p-1}B_n(x)\,dx.$$